# iPhone - Custom buttons on a search bar?

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

How can I add custom buttons to a search bar.

I'm looking to add a "Next" and "Previous" button to the search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can employ the method proposed here: [Adding button to left of UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482612/adding-button-to-left-of-uisearchbar)

Just add your UISearchBar to a Navigation bar with the following layout: PrevButton | SearchInput | NextButton