# additional button on uisearchbar

Tags: uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, cancel-button

I would like to add another button next to the cancel button on the uisearchbar. This button appears just like the cancel button only when the user clicks on the searchbar. What method would be best for doing this?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482612/adding-button-to-left-of-uisearchbar.  See the currently highest voted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3482632/87696