# Adding a Button to a UISearchBar with a TableView and Refresh Control

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uirefreshcontrol

I've been searching for two days for a solution to this problem, and I just can't figure out a cohesive solution.  What I'm trying to do is:

1. Have a UISearchBar with an extra button to the left like in this thread [Adding button to left of UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482612/adding-button-to-left-of-uisearchbar).
2. Have a table view that shows the results that the UISearchBar is not part of, so that the search bar stays on screen even if you scroll down in the table view. I was only able to do this by separating the tableview and the search bar, meaning I can't use UITableViewController
3. Have refresh control on the table view.  From this thread [UIRefreshControl without UITableViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497940/uirefreshcontrol-without-uitableviewcontroller) it looks like I can't do this in a supported way if I can't use a tableViewController.

I've tried using the UIToolbar solution to adding a button to a UISearchBar, but the gradients don't really blend, so I'd prefer not to use that solution.  I also haven't had any luck using any of the code snippets I've found here to add the button in a subclass in a way that can support autolayout for rotation.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could make a custom object that just stacks a UISearchBar on top of a UINavigationBar and then use a UIBarButtonItem for the button that you are talking about. If you make this a re-usable custom object, you should be able to implement it app-wide.