# UISearchBar with a left button

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uisearchbar

I'm looking for having a UiSearchBar with a button at the left.
I've been reading **[this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482612/adding-button-to-left-of-uisearchbar/17089376#17089376)**, and following the steps described by KennyTM, but I don't manage to have the same result.

Here is what I've got :

[image]

As you can see my search bar don't have the same color than my navigation bar.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for( id view in search.subviews) {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            UIImageView *img = (UIImageView *)view;
            img.image = nil;
        }
    }
search.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"searchbar.png"];
```

search is the object for `UISearchbar`

Comment: work fine with `search.backgroundImage = [UIColor clearColor];`

Answer (score 0):

```
/ button
UIBarButtonItem *settingsButtonItem = // create settings button

// search bar
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 260, 44)];
UIBarButtonItem *searchBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBar];
[searchBar release];

// toolbar is UIToolbar
[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:settingsButtonItem, searchBarButtonItem nil] animated:NO];
```

Please implement above code may it help lot.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but trying to implement your solution (which unfortunately leads to the problem of this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482612/adding-button-to-left-of-uisearchbar too), I've been undoing the modification and obtaining the desired result. But thanks for the help.