# How to add custom button to UISearchBar

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uisearchbar

I'm trying to customize my searchbar.
I need to add two buttons to my searchbar view.
I can't to add searchbar to navigationbar, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482612/adding-button-to-left-of-uisearchbar)
Here what i'm trying to do:

```
CGRect searchFrame = CGRectMake(7, 225, 30, 30);
self.searchButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.searchButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"magnifier"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.searchButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.searchButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"magnifier"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.searchButton setFrame:searchFrame];

UITextField *searchField = [self.textSearchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
[searchField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[searchField setLeftView:UITextFieldViewModeNever];
[searchField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
searchField.frame = CGRectMake(10, 7, 200, 30);

[self.textSearchBar addSubview:self.searchButton];

[self.textSearchBar reloadInputViews];
```

But it doesn't work. Can do it? How to add to searchBar subViews?