# How to add a custom button next to search bar in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In a SwiftUI NavigationView there is a property called [`.searchable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/searchable(text:placement:)). How can I add a custom button next to the search bar generated by searchable?

[image: iOS screenshot showing arrow to right side of iOS navigation search bar]

If this is not possible, how can I build this whole thing from scratch (ideally without falling back to UIKit) and still have it get the nice behavior of the searchable search field (e.g. in but below the toolbar, hides by default at top).

Comment: Have you tried extending/modifying the `.searchable` modifier or overriding the default appearance?

Comment: In answer the @Mr Developer, I don't see any way to override the behavior of searchable such that it would affect the toolbar. I can of course customize what shows up *under* the search bar, but that's not the goal. The only option I'm aware of is to fall back to UIKit to solve this, but I'd like to know if there is a SwiftUI way to do this (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037578/add-filter-button-to-uisearchcontroller).

Comment: Does this help? https://betterprogramming.pub/swiftui-custom-search-bar-lazyvstack-with-sections-and-section-index-6091da436c83 This is about how to build a custom search bar - you could likely add in your own button too.